# how do I use the ternary in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm a bit new to ruby and have been trying to understand the ternary operator for a while now but it isn't getting through to me.

Here's the code I've been experimenting with recently:

**goal:** Greet one or two people, accepting both one or two people as arguments and greeting respectively.

I'm aware the code I passed into the ternary is long and that might be causing the issue? Anyway, all help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance. Here's the original code I wrote followed by what I tried to convert into a ternary. The original code works fine, it's the second that isn't working.

```
def greet(person_1, person_2=nil)
    if person_2.nil?
        p "Hey " + person_1
    else
        p "Hey " + person_1 + " and " + person_2
    end
end

greet("Chao")
greet("Chao", "Arittro")

RESULT: "Hey Chao"
RESULT: "Hey Chao and Arittro"
```

```
def greet(person_1, person_2=nil)
    person_2.nil? ? p ("Hey " + person_1) : p ("Hey " + person_1 + " and " + person_2)
end

greet("Chao")
greet("Chao", "Arittro")

RESULT: "syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '(')"
```

Comment: A suggestion: `"Hey #{person_1}"` and `"Hey #{person_1} and #{person_2}"` maybe read nicer than expressions like `"Hey " + person 1 + " and " + person_2`.

Comment: @ChrisDutton That's true, thx.

Comment: Also, you can pass the return value of a condition to `p`. Consider: `p(person_2.nil? ? "Hey #{person_1}" : "Hey #{person_1} and #{person_2}")`

Comment: @DavidVenegas : Since the true **and** the false branch do just a `p`, only with different arguments, I would put the `p` outside and write a `p("Hey " + person_1 + (person_2.nil? ? '' : " and " + person_2))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are the spaces between `p` and `()`.

This should work

```rb
def greet(person_1, person_2=nil)
    person_2.nil? ? p("Hey " + person_1) : p("Hey " + person_1 + " and " + person_2)
end
```

As this is just an example it's fine but using the ternary operator here in a real application would make the code very very difficult to understand. Most people would prefer the original implementation you posted.

Comment: Yeah, the original implementation is much better to understand

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider to accept the answer.

Comment: Omg. God i feel dumb. Thank you, yes this fixed it